# Yii CJuiDatePicker - second instance on page not opening directly after first

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.14 with YiiBooster 2.0.0 and have a strange issue with a form that contains these two instances of the standard Yii CJuiDatePicker:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'name'=>'dateRange[start]',
            'value'=>'',
            'options'=>array(
                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                    'changeMonth'=> true,
                    'changeYear'=> true,
                    'showButtonPanel'=> true,
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:75px;margin-right:10px;', 'placeholder'=>Yii::t('portal', 'start'))
    ));
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'name'=>'dateRange[end]',
            'value'=>'',
            'options'=>array(
                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                    'changeMonth'=> true,
                    'changeYear'=> true,
                    'showButtonPanel'=> true,
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:75px;','placeholder'=>Yii::t('portal', 'end'))
    ));
```

Basically I can click into the first input field and the date picker appears. However, when I now click directly into the other input field the first date picker closes but the second one does not open. I have to click somewhere else first and then click into the second field again to make it appear.

I guess there's some kind of focus issue? Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is not because of you. Do not worry :)

Comment: Ok... anything I can do to get around this issue!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem...

Looks like when

```
'showAnim'=>'fold'
```

is used the focus is not given to the second date picker quickly enough. As soon as I remove this from the options it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this also work

'id' => 'appendedInputButtons',